# Why does my BertForSequenceClassification run two times more than my BertForTokenClassification?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am running a sequential NER and RE, using the Huggingface library. The hyperparameters, early stopping rules, dataset are all the same. The code is different for both of them, but I find it hard to ascertain what factors could contribute to the RE model training 2x more (10h for NER vs 20h for RE). I am wondering - have you experienced the same? Could a large number of labels (around 30) explain this? The code is probably too long to put there, with all the preprocessing and yadda yadda, so I am wondering about your general experiences of what could be causing such issue.